# Fast way to convert SQLAlchemy objects to Python dicts

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this query that returns a list of student objects:

```
query = db.session.query(Student).filter(Student.is_deleted == false())
query = query.options(joinedload('project'))
query = query.options(joinedload('image'))
query = query.options(joinedload('student_locator_map'))
query = query.options(subqueryload('attached_addresses'))
query = query.options(subqueryload('student_meta'))
query = query.order_by(Student.student_last_name, Student.student_first_name,
                           Student.student_middle_name, Student.student_grade, Student.student_id)
query = query.filter(filter_column == field_value)
students = query.all()
```

The query itself does not take much time. The problem is converting all these objects (can be 5000+) to Python dicts. It takes over a minute with this many objects.Currently, the code loops thru the objects and converts using to_dict(). I have also tried _dict__ which was much faster but this does not convert all relational objects it seems.

How can I convert all these Student objects and related objects quickly?

Comment: this is likely a deferred loading issue... you could try switching the `subqueryload`s to `joinedload`s if you are actually using those attributes, which may make the query take longer, but the subsequent operations faster. i assume you have read this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html but playing with those options in the ORM objects & the query can help...

Comment: i switched subqueryloads to joinedloads. just as slow

Comment: but i do think youre on to something with the deferred loading issue. ive referred to the docs but it hasnt clicked yet. in this scenario, am i hitting the db everytime i want to get the object's attached_address?

Comment: according to my understanding of the docs, joinedloading and subqueryloading are both eager loads so does that mean related objects are loaded upon initial query not when accessed as is the case with lazy loading?this woud seem to be what i want as its faster than querying the db everytime the object is accessed individually? lemme know if my understanding is incorrect

Comment: if these objects are eager loading as im assuming then it may be that THEIR related objects are lazy loading by default. for example, attached_addresses have their own relationship with address and address_type so it may be that these are lazy loaded with every iteration thru the loop thus hitting the db once for each object to retrieve these other objects...

Comment: as I understand it, joinedload = eager when you do the initial request, subqueryload = fetch this attribute for all results of the original query when you hit the attribute in any of the records returned. but i would agree that it's probably a relationship further down that might be causing issues. you can pass those are arguments to joinedload as well, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query = query.options(joinedload('attached_addresses').joinedload('address'))
```

By chaining address joinedload to attached_addresses I was able to significantly speed up the query.

My understanding of why this is the case:

Address objects were not being loaded with the initial query. Every iteration thru the loop, the db would get hit to retrieve the Address object. With joined load, Address objects are now loaded upon initial query.

Thanks to Corley Brigman for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you...

```
from collections import defaultdict

def query_to_dict(student_results):
   result = defaultdict(list)
   for obj in student_results:
      instance = inspect(obj)
      for key, x in instance.attrs.items():
         result[key].append(x.value)
   return result

output = query_to_dict(students)
```